# Weird problem with pgfsys-xetex.def and fadings (xelatex)

Tags: beamer, xetex, texlive, debian

```
[...]
Your graphic driver pgfsys-xetex.def does not support fadings
[...]
```

That's what the following MWE returns:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{block}{}
Some text
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I extracted this from my presentation which compiles fine on OSX with MacTeX 2011 (and xelatex). Now on Debian with a fresh net-installed TeXLive 2011, I run into this error.

Comment: There was a bug in `beamer` v3.18 that may be the cause. Please try downloading `beamer` from CTAN and testing with that.